# Why is the following warning being thrown : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm currently trying to learn Protractor, currently writing tests for a login form but some of my tests keep generating the following warning:

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6JhL.png)

The very last test, which is throwing the warning all it's doing is using the navigateToLogin() which is called in the beforeEach() and expect(true).toBeTruthy(). If i delete all the tests expect one of the ones that is having this behaviour, no warning is thrown.

Would anyone be able to shed any light as to how i can get protractor to navigate without getting these warnings?

```
async navigateToLogin(): Promise<unknown>{
    return browser.get('http://localhost:4200/login');
  }

 describe('Login', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    page = new AppPage();
    await page.navigateToLogin();
  });
it('should not navigate from login if password is incorrect', async () => {
    const email = await element(by.id('email'));
    email.sendKeys('l@l.com');
    const password = await element(by.id('password'));
    password.sendKeys('2141212d1e');
    expect(await element(by.id('email')).getAttribute('value')).toBe('l@l.com');
    expect(await element(by.id('password')).getAttribute('value')).toBe('2141212d1e');
    const button = await element(by.buttonText('Login'));
    button.click();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/login');
  });
  it('should be disabled with no inputs, with either input missing or email is not valid ', async () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say this, but protractor ends it's era - https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/5502, I thought I had to mention this since you're just learning it

Back to your issue, normally, `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` and `StaleElementReferenceError` are distinct errors. I guess one might trigger another. But I would start with the first one. If this doesn't help, we will see what causes another.

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` means you had a Promise and didn't explicitly handled (instructed what to do about it). A promise [can have one of three states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise): pending, fulfilled or rejected. You can resolve a promise either by using `.then()` or `await`. The second option has more advantages in my opinion.

Having said that, lets see what is a Promise in protractor:

- [sendKeys](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.sendKeys) returns Promise
- [click](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.click) returns Promise

[element](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder) on the other hand, doesn't return Promise

Considering all of this, your code should be

```
async navigateToLogin(): Promise<unknown>{
  return browser.get('http://localhost:4200/login');
}

describe('Login', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    page = new AppPage();
    await page.navigateToLogin();
  });
  it('should not navigate from login if password is incorrect', async () => {
    const email = element(by.id('email'));
    await email.sendKeys('l@l.com');
    const password = element(by.id('password'));
    await password.sendKeys('2141212d1e');
    expect(await element(by.id('email')).getAttribute('value')).toBe('l@l.com');
    expect(await element(by.id('password')).getAttribute('value')).toBe('2141212d1e');
    const button = element(by.buttonText('Login'));
    await button.click();
    expect(await browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/login');
  });
  it('should be disabled with no inputs, with either input missing or email is not valid ', async () => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, in particular about protractor being on the way out. I updated the code on two consecutive tests ( one for incorrect password the other for incorrect email) which caused the second one to fail.
![fail output](https://ibb.co/HNS60DN).
However when i run the test by itself it passes

Comment: I still don't see you using `await` everywhere where needed